# Multiprocessing pool map on multiple dataframes produce TypeError

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-multiprocessing, python-3.8

I have list of files that I want to import into pandas dataframe, each file is at least 100 MB.

```
# current path of working directory for jupyter notebook and CSV files in Google Colab
file_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/New York Bike Share'

# getting file names within the directory and sort file name
file_names = glob(path.join(file_dir, '*-citibike-tripdata.csv'))
file_names

['/content/drive/MyDrive/New York Bike Share/201901-citibike-tripdata.csv',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/New York Bike Share/201902-citibike-tripdata.csv',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/New York Bike Share/201903-citibike-tripdata.csv',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/New York Bike Share/201904-citibike-tripdata.csv',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/New York Bike Share/201905-citibike-tripdata.csv',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/New York Bike Share/201906-citibike-tripdata.csv',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/New York Bike Share/201907-citibike-tripdata.csv',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/New York Bike Share/201908-citibike-tripdata.csv',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/New York Bike Share/201909-citibike-tripdata.csv',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/New York Bike Share/201910-citibike-tripdata.csv',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/New York Bike Share/201911-citibike-tripdata.csv',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/New York Bike Share/201912-citibike-tripdata.csv']
```

I try to breakdown each file in pieces of dataframe with the help of parameters such as chunksize, usecols etc in read_csv method.

```
cols = [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14]

col_names = ['duration', 'time_start', 'station_name_start', 'station_latitude_start', 'station_longitude_start', 
             'station_name_end', 'station_latitude', 'station_longitude_end', 'user_type', 'birth_year', 'gender']

col_type = {
    'duration': np.int32,
    'station_latitude_start': np.float32,
    'station_longitude_start': np.float32,
    'station_latitude': np.float32,
    'station_longitude_end': np.float32,
    'user_type': 'category',
    'birth_year': 'object',
    'gender': 'category'
}

def create_df(file):

    t = pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=100_000, usecols=cols, names=col_names, dtype=col_type, parse_dates=['time_start'], header=0)

    return t

def merge_df(ls):

    f = reduce(lambda a, b: pd.concat([a, b], ignore_index=True), ls)

    return f
```

All files combined will produce a dataframe of 2GB+, hence I run a trial with 3 csv files.

```
df_list = []

for f in file_names[0:3]:
    for chunk in create_df(f):
        df_list.append(chunk)

df_list[0].info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100000 entries, 0 to 99999
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column                   Non-Null Count   Dtype         
---  ------                   --------------   -----         
 0   duration                 100000 non-null  int32         
 1   time_start               100000 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 2   station_name_start       100000 non-null  object        
 3   station_latitude_start   100000 non-null  float32       
 4   station_longitude_start  100000 non-null  float32       
 5   station_name_end         100000 non-null  object        
 6   station_latitude         100000 non-null  float32       
 7   station_longitude_end    100000 non-null  float32       
 8   user_type                100000 non-null  category      
 9   birth_year               100000 non-null  object        
 10  gender                   100000 non-null  category      
dtypes: category(2), datetime64[ns](1), float32(4), int32(1), object(3)
memory usage: 5.2+ MB

merge_df(df_list).info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3238991 entries, 0 to 3238990
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column                   Dtype         
---  ------                   -----         
 0   duration                 int32         
 1   time_start               datetime64[ns]
 2   station_name_start       object        
 3   station_latitude_start   float32       
 4   station_longitude_start  float32       
 5   station_name_end         object        
 6   station_latitude         float32       
 7   station_longitude_end    float32       
 8   user_type                category      
 9   birth_year               object        
 10  gender                   category      
dtypes: category(2), datetime64[ns](1), float32(4), int32(1), object(3)
memory usage: 166.8+ MB
```

I try to speed up the process of producing similar result with help of  'multiprocessing' Pool and got TypeError.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(8)

pool.map(merge_df, df_list)

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Appreciate your advice on the error.

Comment: In `merge_df` you pass in a dataframe and then it is supposed to merge with which other dataframe?

Comment: @yudhiesh `merge_df` actually takes in a list of multiple data frames and merge them into single dataframe.